# TFS 2013 goes offline

Tags: tfs, iis-8

I experience an issue with the TFS recently where it goes offline (it becomes unavailable).

It works when I restart IIS by running the command of: iisreset/ noforce .

The hosting server runs on a Windows Server 2012..

I wonder is there anyway to resolve this without having to restart IIS on the hosting server everyday!

Please let us know if you had a similar experience.

Many thanks.

**Update**

I found these two messages in the event log:

- Level: Information:

"A worker process with process id of '9156' serving application pool 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed."

And also this one:

- Level: Warning:

A process serving application pool 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '9156'.

I also found that the TFS Database backup location is full, so I emptied that, but that didn't work.

TFS Works generally, but it fails almost at noon time everyday.

Comment: What's in the event log?

Comment: @DanielMann I updated the question with details from the Event Viewer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar experience recently. I would highly recommend looking at the event log.
In my case it turned out (after a lot of investigation) that the IIS ASP.Net web cache for TFS was corrupt.

1. Stop IIS.
2. Delete the tfs web cache/folder in the temp ASP.Net folder
   ( Something like this
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
   Files\tfs)
3. Restart IIS